# Error in render: TypeError: Cannot read property title of undefined In laravel vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Im having a trouble on how can I display data in v-for. I've been following this link video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhyA8OsA8OI&list=PLKpfEl4N7tRqIx4VZmuZBnUQ6vG4uDgq7&index=4)time `9:29` but it show the error cannot read property. It is possbile to the version of laravel?  It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

> Template

```
    <template>
    <div>
      <h1>The number is : {{views}}</h1>
      <button @click="updateCounter(1)">Increase</button>
      <button @click="updateCounter(-1)">Increase</button>
      <br>
      <br><br>

      <div v-for ="(user,i) in blogs" :key="i">
          <h1>{{user.title}}</h1>
          <p>{{user.post}}</p>

    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

> Script

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            views : 0,
            blogs : [],

        }
    },
    methods:{
        updateCounter(number){
            this.views += number;
        }
    },
    created(){

        this.views = 100
        let posts = [{title: 'this is blog 1', 'post' : 'this is blog post 1', id:1},
                {title: 'this is blog 2', 'post' : 'this is blog post 2', id:2},
                {title: 'this is blog 3', 'post' : 'this is blog post 3', id:3},
                {title: 'this is blog 4', 'post' : 'this is blog post 4', id:4},
            ,]
        this.blogs = posts
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Typo... You have an extra `,` at the end of your array (after the fourth item in array). You need to remove it and it works fine. Technically you have two extra `,` as your fourth item is the last one in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine just remove the extra `'Comma'`

Change `,]  with ]`

Answer (score 1):

On the created function you should use

```
created(){

        this.views = 100
        let posts = [{title: 'this is blog 1', 'post' : 'this is blog post 1', id:1},
                {title: 'this is blog 2', 'post' : 'this is blog post 2', id:2},
                {title: 'this is blog 3', 'post' : 'this is blog post 3', id:3},
                {title: 'this is blog 4', 'post' : 'this is blog post 4', id:4}
            ,]
        this.blogs = posts
    }
```